# Special character

Tags: symbols

I need to put a weird symbol into regular text. I tracked down the [UTF details](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=ʿ&mode=char) of it, that page describes it as: "MODIFIER LETTER LEFT HALF RING"

How can I find out the TeX code for it?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Maybe for Greek language?

Comment: It's needed for the name of an historic persian individual.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, finally found it on a [useful webpage](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/biblio/biber/documentation/utf8-macro-map.html) (always 5 minutes after posting on SE...)

```
\textlefthalfring
```